# Virtual address range of a process

Tags: linux, memory, process, operating-system, linux-kernel

In short: is the virtual address space of a process contiguous?

I need to know something about virtual address allocated to a process by the kernel. Please correct me if I am wrong as I proceed.

On process creation, the kernel allocated virtual memory to the process and stores the starts and ends of the virtual addresses of the different segments of the process in the `mm_struct` in the `task_struct`.

Now say the a process has run out of the heap and needs to increase the heap size.calls `brk()`.

If the virtual address range is contiguous, is the newly allocated chunk of heap provided from outside the range that was allocated originally for this process? Or is it allocated in a way that the new chunk is adjacent to the original one. What if there is no space for that (because the memory mapped segment is lying there). how is it kept track of?
If the virtual address range is not contiguous, how does the `vm_struct` keep track of the different chunks of the address ranges for the heap (or any other segment)?

Can you please clear my concept on that?

Answer (score 8):

No, the virtual address space of a process is not necessarily contiguous. In the old days, a process obtained memory through [`brk`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/brk.2.html), which indeed forced the process heap to be a contiguous zone of memory. Nowadays memory allocation is done through [`mmap`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html), which can manipulate the process's virtual memory page by page.

If you're curious about the kernel side of things, I recommend two references:

- Read a book on the Linux kernel, such as [*Linux Device Drivers* by Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro Rubini, and Greg Kroah-Hartman](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), in particular [chapter 8 (Allocating Memory)](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch08.pdf).
- Browse the kernel code through [LXR, the Linux kernel cross-reference](http://lxr.linux.no/linux). The memory management code is in the [`mm` directory](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/mm); start with [`mmap.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/mm/mmap.c) or [`mm.h`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/include/linux/mm.h).

If you'd like to explore around on your system, you can see each process's memory mapping in `/proc/$pid/maps`. See [How do I read from /proc/$pid/mem under Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux) for more information.

Comment: I think dlmalloc derivatives still use `brk()` for allocations under a certain threshold, though I'll admit I haven't looked at this recently. OTOH, IIRC, OpenBSD uses `mmap()` for every allocation.

Answer (score 8):

The virtual address space is not contiguous. See the output of `cat /proc/<pid>/mem`.

When starting a process, the kernel allocates several mappings for the dynamic linker and for the process itself. Afterwards, the dynamic linker allocates more mappings via `mmap()`, and the process can allocate more mappings via `mmap()` and extend the heap via `brk()`. `malloc()` on dlmalloc and derivatives uses `brk()` for allocations shorter than a threshold and `mmap()` for allocations larger than or equal to that threshold (around 128K IIRC).

In any case, when calling `mmap()`, the kernel usually maps memory far from the heap, so there is usually enough space to extend the heap. If there is no virtual space left to extend the heap, `brk()` will fail.

Comment: The contents of `/proc/<pid>/maps` is probably what you should look at first, suppie.

Answer (score 1):

thanks..
after going through the said literatures as per my understanding,

the virtual address space is not contiguous throughout the process, as well as not even throughout a given memory segment. and the different chunks of virtual address ranges are managed in the kernel using an AVL tree of `vm_area_struct`(*virtual memory areas*). thereby easily adding and deleting chunks of *virtual memory areas* to the `task_struct` of the process. ref: [Virtual Memory](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=322). but the *virtual memory areas* in itself are contiguous.

i.e. in effect the `task_struct` contains a pointer to `mm_struct` which contains a pointer to heads of AVL trees (one tree for every memory region). the nodes of the tree are nothing but `vm_area_struct`s which has start and end pointers to mark the start and end of the *virtual memory areas*

thanks a lot